# achartenginge rendering correctly the first time, but when I remove it and add one with different datapoints to linearlayout, the presets dissappear

Tags: android, achartengine

I am creating a chartview to display mood for different days of the year. It renders correctly the first time. But when I press my buttons for "next" and "previous" days, the datapoints come in correctly, but the charts presets do not. For example, the chart is no longer clickable, and I can't pan anymore (I was able to do both before). Below is the code. What am I doing wrong here?

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    mContext = this.getActivity();
    mDbHelper=new CalendarDbAdapter(mContext);
    mDbHelper.open();
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_graph, container, false);
    Button next = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.next);
    Button previous = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.previous);
    Day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
    Year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    chartView = generate(Day, Year);
    layout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.graph);  
    layout.addView(chartView);

    next.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {
            Day++;
            if (Day > 365)
            {
                Day = 0;
                Year++;
            }
            layout.removeView(chartView);
            chartView = generate(Day, Year);
            layout.addView(chartView);

        }
    });
    previous.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {

        public void onClick(View arg0) 
        {
            Day--;
            if (Day < 0)
            {
                Day = 0;
                Year--;
            }
            layout.removeView(chartView);
            chartView = generate(Day, Year);
            layout.addView(chartView);
        }

    });

    chartView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            SeriesSelection seriesSelection = chartView.getCurrentSeriesAndPoint();
            Log.e("series select is",""+seriesSelection);
            Log.e("I was","clicked");
        }

    });
    return view;

    }

@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
    mDbHelper.close();
}

public GraphicalView generate(long Day, long Year)
{
    Cursor calendar = mDbHelper.fetchDay(Year, Day);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();  
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, (int)Year);  
    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, (int)Day);  
    Log.e("Day is",""+Day);
    Date date = cal.getTime();  
    String sDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").format(date);  
    minutes.clear();
    mood.clear();
        while (calendar.moveToNext())
        {
            Hour = Float.valueOf((calendar.getInt(calendar.getColumnIndexOrThrow(CalendarDbAdapter.COLUMN_NAME_MINUTES))))/60;
            minutes.add(Hour);
            mood.add(calendar.getInt(calendar.getColumnIndexOrThrow(CalendarDbAdapter.COLUMN_NAME_FEELING)));
        }


    if (! calendar.moveToFirst())
    {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "No events this day!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    XYValueSeries series = new XYValueSeries("Mood by Time"); 
    if (minutes.size() > 0)
    {
        for( int i = 0; i < minutes.size(); i++)
        {
            series.add(minutes.get(i), mood.get(i));
        }
    }

    XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
    dataset.addSeries(series);

    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer(); // Holds a collection of XYSeriesRenderer and customizes the graph
    XYSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();// This will be used to customize line 1
    mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);
    double[] limits = new double [] {0, 23, 0, 7};
    mRenderer.setPanLimits(limits);
    mRenderer.setPanEnabled(true, false);
    for (int i = 0; i < 23; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            mRenderer.addXTextLabel(i, ""+(i+12)+" AM");

        }
        if (i > 0 && i < 12)
        {
            mRenderer.addXTextLabel(i, ""+(i+" AM"));
        }

        if (i == 12)
        {
            mRenderer.addXTextLabel(i, ""+(i +" PM"));
        }

        if (i > 12 && i < 24)
        {
            mRenderer.addXTextLabel(i, ""+((i -12 ) +" PM"));
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
        mRenderer.addYTextLabel(i, "Terrible");
        }

        if (i == 3)
        {
            mRenderer.addYTextLabel(i, "Neutral");
        }

        if (i == 6)
        {
            mRenderer.addYTextLabel(i, "Fantastic");
        }

    }
    mRenderer.setYAxisMax(7);
    mRenderer.setYAxisMin(0);
    mRenderer.setXAxisMax(23);
    mRenderer.setPointSize(5);
    mRenderer.setChartTitle(sDate);
    mRenderer.setClickEnabled(true);
    // Customization time for line 1!
    renderer.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    renderer.setLineWidth(3);
    renderer.setPointStyle(PointStyle.CIRCLE);
    renderer.setFillPoints(true);

    // Customization time for line 2!

    GraphicalView chartView;

    chartView = ChartFactory.getLineChartView(mContext, dataset, mRenderer);
    return chartView;

}
```

Comment: OK so now I'm seeing that it has something to do with   mRenderer.setClickEnabled(true); when I take that out I can scroll on all instances of the chartview. but why would i be able to scroll AND click the default chart, and not be able to scroll OR click when i press the next and previous buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whoops the onlicklistener was only responding the initial view. I moved the onclicklistener to my chartview method and it's working.